# Bad Dates in iReport corrupting jasper server report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am getting null dates in iReport and some dates with 0000-00-00 and some with invalid dates. Aside from changing the database itself I need to be able to clear them or something. I was thinking of handling this on the SQL side of things, opinions or solutions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of accomplishing this on the SQL side:

```
IF(yourtable.yourdatefield < '1970-01-01',
CAST(yourtable.yourdatefield AS CHAR(10)),yourtable.yourdatefield) AS yourdatefield
```